# Why do not the ripples on a pond form a 3 dimensional wave?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, spacetime-dimensions

I can see that that the expansion of the the circles happens in a two dimensional plane. Therefore, we say that a two dimensional wave is formed. But, why cannot we count the vertical disturbance so that it becomes the third dimension (and then we can say a three dimensional wave is formed)?

Is it because the circle-based wave propagates while the vertical one does not?
Or is it because the pattern of the way, the vertical disturbance moves, does not "fit" that of the circular waves?

Comment: Don't confuse the math with the reality.  The reality is water molecules moving in a circular motion, and influencing adjacent molecules to move along.  The "waves" are a mathematical model that we use to describe the disturbance, and how it moves.  The _disturbance_ can only travel parallel to the surface of the pond.

Answer (score 3):

There are two different kinds of wave here. The ones that you see on the surface are the (IMO) badly named [Gravity Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave) (not to be confused with a [Gravitational Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave)), which is the familiar phenomenon of waves on the ocean surface and arise at the interfaces between dissimilar fluids. Their phase velocity is $\sqrt{\frac{g}{k}}$ and the group velocity $\frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt{\frac{g}{k}}$, where $k$ is the wavenumber. For a splash from a rock several centimeters in diameter, $k$ is of the order of $2\,\pi/0.05{\rm m^{-1}}$ so that the phase speed is of the order of meters per second or less.

The other kind is the [Acoustic Waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_wave). These are essentially sound in the medium, and propagate at speeds $c=\sqrt{\frac{B}{\rho}}$ (where $B$ is the medium's bulk modulus and $\rho$ its density) typically two orders of magnitude faster than gravity waves.

So the disturbance is indeed three dimensional: the waves propagating into the mediums away from the surface are acoustic waves and are gone within a fraction of a second, leaving only the slow moving gravity wave as the only remaining evidence of the disturbance.

Comment: Note that surface tension also gives rise to propagation of surface waves/ripples. Might want to include them for completeness of an otherwise lovely answer.

Answer (score 0):

We (humans) exist in and so perceive our world as one of 3 dimensions in space. Although some physical phenomena we observe may appear to be 2 dimensional in nature, if observed more closely we will see that behavior poking its way into the third dimension somewhere. Strictly speaking 2 dimensional behavior cannot exist in a three dimensional world. While the surface waves you cite might appear to be 2 dimensional, closer examination indeed shows a finer structure including the vertical dimension that further defines the waves and crests moving outward from the initial point of disturbance.

To observe strictly 2 dimensional physical behavior, one must somehow find their way to [Flatland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland).

Comment: It's true that surface waves on a pond exist in a three dimensional world, and they could not exist without three dimensional motion of the water, but we call them "two dimensional" because they are confined to the surface of the pond.  Only two coordinates are needed to describe any direction in which they can propagate.

Comment: @jameslarge Yes but when you resign yourself to the 2 dimensional description of the behavior you are settling for an approximate description. While a 2 dimensional description may give you as much as you need to know for practical purposes, the 3 dimensional description gets you a step closer to what's really going on. But of course the 3 dimensional description is also an approximation, as **all** models are approximations. But as Box said many are useful. As engineers and scientists we decide if our models have reached the point of usefulness!

Comment: All _useful_ descriptions are approximate.  It's the throwing away of irrelevant details that _make_ them useful.  It is often useful to describe the ripples on the surface of water as mathematical waves propagating through a 2D space.  But the model that is useful in solving one problem may not fit some other problem.  For example, if you want to know _why_ ripples on a pond propagate in a wave-like way, then you must necessarily talk about the momentum of water moleules at _and below_ the surface (i.e., you enter the third dimension.)

Answer (score 0):

The waves are of 1D,2D,3D and if their nature is described within those dimensions of space.
**1D** Waves : The direction of propagation of wave and the oscillation of the particles of wave are in same direction.(Spring Waves)
**2D** Waves : The direction of propagation of wave and the oscillation of the particles of wave are perpendicular to each other in the same plane.(water waves)
**3D** Waves : The direction of propagation of wave in one plane and the oscillation of the particles of wave in two different planes and the planes are perpendicular to each other.
(Light waves)

Answer (score 0):

They are three dimensional! Two of the dimensions tell us where to locate a point on the surface, and the third tells us how high the wave is above the surface. Or to put it another way, the value of the wave *is* the "vertical disturbance".