# Ripples through a uniform ball of water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves

Let's say the earth was a giant blob of water, with a still surface. Now, suppose I drop a drop of water at the north pole. What happens next? I don't know how gravity is going to influence this. Assuming the ripples last long enough (side question, do ripples fade because of viscous loss and because the energy spreads out (inverse square?) and the waves become imperceptible?), I imagine that the ripples can expand as they go towards the equator, and then shrink and reach the south pole. Now, will the ripple "pass through itself" and travel back up, or will it pinch out a drop of water, which will bounce and drop back and repeat the cycle?

Also, the ripples are 3 dimensional, right? As in, it's a disc of compression passing through the volume of the sphere, so in this case, what shapes will the disc go through? It starts out concave upwards (up being north), does it become flat at the equator and so on? I found this post: [Why do not the ripples on a pond form a 3 dimensional wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202217/).

Comment: **Calling Randall Monroe**  :-).  Great What-If question.  The first thing to consider is how a blob of water that massive will behave -  almost certainly it'll be some sort of seriously heated and compressed state near the center. I don't know for sure which, if any, of the solid forms of water can exist at the temperatures that will be generated.    Now, if you instead assume a spherical solid Earth with, say a 1-km layer of water everywhere (and then adjust for rotational rate leading to equatorial bulge), you have a different scenario.